# Getting Cluster's centers in real-time using spark StreamingKMeans

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Apache Spark (pyspark - python) streaming to cluster my data.
For doing this, I'm using `StreamingKMeans` from `pyspark.mllib.clustering` library.

I've managed to correctly cluster my data but I have a problem to access the cluster's center in real-time
(I need to access the cluster's position for each newly received datapoint). 
My function always returns the same positions for the clusters (the clusters are supposed to change continuously).

```
#amazon_stream_data: key-value pairs, date as key and features vectors as values
#=> ('2014-01-01',[1.5,1.05,0.3])


# We create a model with random clusters and specify the number of clusters to find
model = StreamingKMeans(k=4, decayFactor=1.0).setRandomCenters(3,1.0,0)

# Now register the streams for training and testing and start the job,
# printing the predicted cluster assignments on new data points as they arrive.
model.trainOn(amazon_stream_data.map(lambda x:x[1]) #train on features 

result_stream = model.predictOnValues(amazon_stream_data) # predict clusters foreach feature
#result_stream : key-value pairs, date as key and cluster's index as value
#=> ('2014-01-01', 1)

joined_stream = amazon_stream.join(result_stream) 
# key-value pairs, date as key and tuple of the features and the cluster's index as value
#=> ('2014-01-01', ([1.5,1.05,0.3],1))
```

I want to create a distance stream that represents the distance between the current point to its current cluster's center (the clusters are changing continuously).

To do so, I must get the cluster's position for each point (instead of its index).
I tried:

```
desired_stream = joined_stream\
   .map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0],model.latestModel().clusterCenters[x[1][1]])))
#x[0]: index (date) =>'2014-01-01'
#x[1][0]: features vector => [1.5,1.05,0.3]
#x[1][1]: cluster's index => 1

#desired_stream  supposed to be key-value pairs, 
#date as key and tuple of the features and the cluster's position vector as value
#=> ('2014-01-01', ([1.5,1.05,0.3],[1.6,0.092,0.8]))
```

but the 
`model.latestModel().clusterCenters` always returns the same positions for the clusters (the clusters are supposed to change continuously).